# Jquery mobile integration on plone

Tags: jquery-mobile, plone

I'm working on a Plone site that has JQuery mobile and I have an issue with the medias.

JQuery mobiles creates a neat menu in the web page's home page that links to the differents views of the plone site. The problem is that the medias (like the images) are linked with a weird URL that doesn't exists.

What I mean is the following:

I have an image whose path would be: **url**/competitions-en/red-bull-monte-descend/horaire/red-bull-monte-descend/**vignette_normal**

But in the src param of the img tag what I see it's **url** / **nameOfView** competitions-en/red-bull-monte-descend/horaire/red-bull-monte-descend/**vignette_normal**

I have no idea why JQuery mobile adds the name of the view to the path of the image, tough I do know that if I load the view client side (so instead of going: main menu>view, I load the view in a new tab) there's no problem. JQuery mobile adds the name of the view to the path of the image only when I access the view trough the main page.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Additional information:

This would be the block in the plone template with the first TD generating the img

```
<tr tal:repeat="el python: une_date[1]['horaires']"> 
    <td tal:attributes="class string:categorie ${el/categorie/cls}"> 
        <img tal:attributes="src el/horaire/vignette; alt el/horaire/title_short;" /> 
    </td> 
    <td tal:attributes="class string:competition"> 
        <a tal:content="el/competition/title" tal:attributes="href el/competition/url"></a> 
    </td> 
    <td class="emplacement"> 
        <span tal:content="el/horaire/emplacement"></span> 
    </td> 
    <td class="debut_fin"> 
        <span tal:content="el/horaire/debut">debut</span> - <span tal:content="el/horaire/fin">fin</span> 
    </td> 
    <td class="title" tal:content="el/horaire/title">un titre</td> 
 </tr>
```

Ty,
Axel

Comment: I think it might be related to Base URL metadata in <html> <head>. jQuery Mobile reads it and uses it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/base Check if this tag in fact points to view in the source code.